# async method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asynchronous

I want to create a async method which will open a thread and complete several tasks that is relatively independent to the current http request (for example, sending emails and generating files both of which takes time)

I created the following method

```
private static async Task<T> DoSeparateTask<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    return func();
}
```

and want to use it in such a way:

```
private static void DoSomething()
{
    #step 1 - some code for immediate processing
    #step 2 - some code for generating documents which takes time
    var additionalDocumentGenerationWork = DoSeparateTask<Document>(() =>{
        #additional code for generating Document
       #even though it returns Document, but 99% time it wont be used in this method
    });
    #step 3 - some code for sending SMTP email which takes time
    var additionalDocumentGenerationWork = DoSeparateTask<bool>(() =>{
        #additional code for sending email
        return true;
    });

}
```

Everything compiles, however when I run the web application, it still keeps loading and waiting everything to complete before rendering the web page.  As the 2 additional tasks (email and documents) are not relevant for displaying the webpage,  how can I achieve such by using the async  modifiers?

Or if my understanding of async is wrong... please help me to correct...

Many thanks.

Comment: You should look at the warning that the compiler is giving you, for that `async` method that does not have any `await` statement in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or if my understanding of async is wrong... please help me to correct...

As I explain on my blog, [`async` does not change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html). At the end of the day, you only have one response for each request. To put another way, `async` yields to the thread pool, not to the client.

What you're looking for is a way to do operations *outside* the request/response lifecycle, which is not directly supported by ASP.NET. I describe a few approaches [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html). The best (most reliable) approach is to place the work into a queue, and have an independent backend that processes the queue (such as an Azure worker role).

Comment: What Stephen wrote is spot on, here are a few more options that you can choose from to solve this problem, http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen - it gives me clear direction of what to be done - because each document and email can be easily processed within 1 minute so I have adapted .NET framework 4.5.2 HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem() as you suggested in the blog. It works amazingly!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `DoSeparateTask<T>()` method. Instead, just use `Task.Run<T>()`:

```
private static async Task DoSomething()
{
    // #step 1 - some code for immediate processing
    // #step 2 - some code for generating documents which takes time
    var additionalDocumentGenerationWork1 = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // #additional code for generating Document
        // #even though it returns Document, but 99% time it wont be used in this method
    });

    // #step 3 - some code for sending SMTP email which takes time
    var additionalDocumentGenerationWork2 = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // #additional code for sending email
        return true;
    });
}
```

Note that the type of `additionalDocumentGenerationWork1` and `additionalDocumentGenerationWork2` (you used the same name twice in your example, so I changed it above to make the code legal) are `Document` and `bool` respectively. You can use `additionalDocumentGenerationWork1` in your second task invocation if you like (e.g. to pass the result of the first operation).